# Superclass vs Protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, oop

I've never worked with objective C but have a fair bit of experience with C++.

What exactly is the difference between a superclass and a protocol in objective C? I read that a protocol is essentially a pure virtual class, but is that it? Is a protocol simply a specific type of superclass?

Comment: There is a very useful document about protocol here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A protocol is a contract a class is going to conform to. When a class conforms to a protocol it tells the compiler that it will implement all the methods and all the properties declared in the protocol.
In Objective-C the class additionally needs a superclass. In a lot of cases this is `NSObject`. The superclass implements already a lot of methods (like `isEqual:`). A protocol never implements any methods or defines any property.

Answer (score 1):

A protocol tells which properties/operations a class **must**  implement. A superclass implements them and you can add your own stuff on top.

Answer (score 0):

A protocol defines a set of method definitions that a class or struct must implement, very much like a Java interface.

A superclass is the class from which a given class inherits its method definitions, the implementation for those methods, and the instance and class properties.